# Pass variables from class instance to its extended method

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying to pass a variable to a method in an extended class, but it's not working.

Here's the sample code:

```
class set2 extends set1
{
    function Body($variable) {
    }
}


$start2 = new set2();
$start2->Body('some text');
```

The last line is the part I'm trying to get to work. I'm not sure if I should have a constructor instead to do it or how it's best to get it to work.

I figured it out. I just added a public variable instead and passed its value like this:

```
class set2 extends set1
{
    public $variable = NULL;
    function Body() {
        echo $this->variable;
            }
}


$start2 = new set2();
$start2->variable = 'Some Text';
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working".... there's nothing particularly wrong with this code (besides the fact that you don't actually do anything with `$variable` inside the `Body` method)

Comment: $variable is not accessible in the body for me. The $variable is not in the parent class, just in the child class. So when I add it in the child class, it says missing argument in the original class and defined in this child class.

Comment: Then show a real example, including the parent class..... you're extending the parent class, but the parent doesn't know this

Answer (score 1):

Three different ways of doing what I think you're trying to do:

```
class set1
{
    protected $headVariable;

    function Head() {
        echo $this->headVariable;
    }

    function Body($variable) {
        echo $variable;
    }

    function Foot() {
        echo static::$footVariable;
    }

}


class set2 extends set1
{
    protected static $footVariable;

    function Head($variable) {
        $this->headVariable = $variable;
        parent::Head();
    }

    function Body($variable) {
        parent::Body($variable);
    }

    function Foot($variable) {
        self::$footVariable = $variable;
        parent::Foot();
    }

}


$start2 = new set2();
$start2->Head('some text');
$start2->Body('some more text');
$start2->Foot('yet more text');
```

Comment: Thanks but I think that's much more than I was trying to do.  I essentially just wanted to be able to add new variables into the extended class that weren't defined in the parent class. I added how I solved the problem in my question.